# Connect 4 and neural networks

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to code a Connect 4 - IA based on neural networks.

But it's the first time I use ANN, so I'm completely lost...

I found something that looks great, but need some explanations...

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpZgJ.png)

I'm ok with the input, but I don't understand the number of hiddens.

Also, the output should be the number of the colomn where to put the coin next turn, it means a value between 1 and 7.

But how could I get these values, using a sigmoid function ?

Comment: In what programming language? Or which ANN library?

Comment: Python, with nothing more than numpy !

Comment: In fact, I already coded a very simple 3input-1hidden network and it worked pretty well !

I know how to code the network, but the choice of its structure for my situation is the problem...

Could it be possible to communicate by skype/etc/.. ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Learning to play (from no external information)? Learning to imitate some expert (you got moves of historical-games)? What did you mean by it worked well? Which environment (as outlined above) was used? In general, you would not use sigmoid, but a softmax-layer as final activation, which gives you class-probabilities of column-choices!